# Is it okay to go for walk without bowel movement early in the morning?

Tags: diet, workout, health, jogging, walking

I wake up early in the morning (About half an hour before sunrise). I drink 2 glasses of water. I don't have any bowel movement at that time. My bowel movement occurs most of the times after **2-3** hours later.

For better health, I love to walk in the morning. I walk for around **4-5 Kms**. Is it okay to walk (neither very fast, nor slow) before bowel movement? Would it give me almost same benefits as walking after bowel movement? Or is it harmful?

Further, I would like to know if I change from **walking to jogging**, what would be your answer?

Should I work on changing the bowel movement times or everything is fine?

NOTE: (I'm not overweight. I don't walk (or don't want to jog) to lose weight. It's just because it makes me feel good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poop when you need to poop. For a walk as short as 5km, emptying your bowels beforehand isn't important at all.

Comment: What about jogging 2-3 Kms?

Comment: The same applies. Stop worrying about your bowel movements. Unless you're constipated, or have perpetual diarrhea, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Okay. But I've 2 bowel movements in a day, one in morning one in evening. Is it okay?

Comment: I repeat; Unless you're constipated, or have perpetual diarrhea, you have nothing to worry about.